# pass by reference, cascading function call question

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

```
void setSeat(Knight& t, int a) {
    t.seatingPos = a;

 }
 void Reset(vector<Knight>& a) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    setSeat(a[i], i);
   }
 }
```

each Knight object has an int data member "seatingPosition" ive tried a variety of ways but cant seem to permanently change this value. Reset is called and then setSeat is called. while debugging it shows the value changes but then it doesnt save. am i passing by ref incorrectly?

Comment: What  do you mean by does not save?

Comment: This code looks fine, so the bug is likely somewhere else.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the data member 'seating position' reverts back to its original value

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that streams the reverted value to `std::cout`.

Comment: This code snippet works, after I add code to make it complete.  I bet there is a bug in the code not provided.